# PHP check if user exists PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to implement the function where it will check whether if the user already exists in my database be for it will insert all the registration data but it doesn't seem to work =( could someone please help me identify where the error is. really appreciate all the answer in advance.

```
<?php

require '../ppuyakul/php/db_conn.php';


$message = '';

//Prepare date
$DOB = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['year'].'-'. $_POST['month'].'-'. $_POST['day']));
$accessType = "0";

//Check enpty field
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['fullname']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password_confirmation']) && !empty($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['country']) && !empty($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['day']) && !empty($_POST['month']) && !empty($_POST['year'])):

  // Enter the new user in the database
  $sql = "INSERT INTO assignment2 (fullname, username, email, password, gender, country, state, city, DOB, type) VALUES (:fullname, :username, :email, :password, :gender, :country, :state, :city, :DOB, :type)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->bindParam(':fullname', $_POST['fullname']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
  $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $_POST['gender']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':country', $_POST['country']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':state', $_POST['state']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':city', $_POST['city']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':DOB', $DOB);
  $stmt->bindParam(':type', $accessType);

  $chk = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM assignment2 WHERE username =  :name");
  $chk->bindParam(':name', $username);
  $chk->execute();

  if($chk->rowCount() > 0):
    $message = 'Error ! ! User already exists';
    else:
      if( $stmt->execute() ):
        $message = 'Successfully created new user';
          else:
            $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
          endif; 
      endif;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: How/where is $username set ?

Comment: Hi Paul thanks so much for your reply, I try to declare here   
`$all_rows = $chk->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($all_rows as $row):

      $username = $row["username"];

      $_GLOBAL['username'] = $username;

    endforeach;`

before ` if($chk->rowCount() > 0):`

but still no luck

Comment: I do not see that code in what was originally posted ?  When I searched for $username (before my first comment) there was only one 'hit' on this page. There is no foreach in the above code. Add an else to your rowCount check, and print 'no rows found' (or whatever) to see what you get. You could also echo $username to see what is output.

Comment: A haaa..... I fixed it just simply  add this simple code `$username = $_POST['username'];` what a bumper -.-" thanks so much for your mention about declaration  really help me watch out next time ^^" really appreciated

Comment: For the record, calling `!empty($_POST['day']) && !empty($_POST['month']) && !empty($_POST['year'])` AFTER you declare `$DOB = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['year'].'-'. $_POST['month'].'-'. $_POST['day']));` will not protect your script frim generating Notices/Warnings regarding undeclared variables.

Answer (score 1):

According to @Paul T. I finally found the solution here is the final code, thanks so much again for your help @Paul T.

```
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $chk = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM assignment2 WHERE username =  :name");
  $chk->bindParam(':name', $username);
  $chk->execute();


  if($chk->rowCount() > 0):
    $message = 'Error ! ! User already exists';
    else:
      if( $stmt->execute() ):
        $message = 'Successfully created new user';
          else:
            $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
          endif; 
      endif;
    endif;
```

Comment: You could also have simply used the $_POST['username'] reference at the bind to avoid an extra variable need. You discovered what I was getting at though, that the $username was not set.